# CABasicAnimation Quickly Jumping Before Animation Start

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cabasicanimation, caanimation

[image: Animation Problem]

I have a `CABasicAnimation` animating the `strokeEnd` property of a CAShapeLayer. Every time I add the animation, it quickly jumps through the animation and then goes and does the real animation (as seen in the image above). If I add the animation in the viewDidLoad, this doesn't happen.

Here's my animation code:

```
let progressAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
progressAnim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
progressAnim.duration = 4.5
progressAnim.fromValue = 0.0
progressAnim.toValue = 1.0

progressAnim.removedOnCompletion = false

progressLayer.addAnimation(progressAnim, forKey: "progressAnimation")
progressLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
```

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the last line `progressLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0` might cause the problem, what is its purpose - what happens if you remove it?

Comment: @luk2302 I just tried removing it, and the problem does go away. But it goes and creates a new problem (the reason why I had it there in the beginning): after the animation finishes, the progress bar goes back to its original starting point.

Comment: okay, put the line back and remove the line `progressAnim.removedOnCompletion = false`

Comment: @luk2302 Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: okay, can you tell my why the animation only has a `toValue` of 0.5?

Comment: @luk2302 that was a typo in my SO code. I think I solved the problem though. Will post an answer in a min. Thanks!

Comment: your code works perfectly on my machine, in my playground

Comment: @luk2302 it was working for me as well when I had it my viewDidLoad, but when I moved my animation code into an action it started giving me this problem.

Comment: @luk2302 I just added my answer on what worked for me. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was with the line `progressLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0`. The reason I had that in my code was to stop the animation from going back to it's original values when it finished animating.

The next solution would be to set the `fillMode` to `progressAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards` and `removedOnCompletion` to `progressAnim.removedOnCompletion = false`. This sort of fixed my problem. But it created another. In my code, this solution doesn't update the `strokeEnd` property to the `toValue`.

My final solution was to set the `toValue` to the `strokeEnd` inside `override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool)`.

My animation code:

```
let progressAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        progressAnim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
        progressAnim.duration = animationDuration
        progressAnim.fromValue = 0.0
        progressAnim.toValue = 0.5
        progressAnim.delegate = self

        progressLayer.addAnimation(progressAnim, forKey: "progressAnimation")
```

Code for when animation is complete:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {            
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5
        progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
```